# Data size of a symbol

Tags: c++, c, vxworks

Using the vxWorks API symFind() we can get the address of a global variable knowing its name. Is there a way to know the corresponding size of a symbol?

The fact is that the searched symbol could be of any type and I need to find it at runtime. So I basically can't use the sizeof directive.

Comment: Phew. I had to track this down using Google's cached copy of symLib.h. If you're using the C API, wouldn't it just be `sizeof` the returned variable or a dereference of it?

Comment: @MrGomez The fact is that the searched symbol could be of any type and I need to find it at runtime. So I basically can't use the sizeof directive.

Comment: @greydet: if you don't know the _type_ of the symbol, it cannot be used.  Period.  Ergo, I think you can know the type, ergo, you can use `sizeof`  If those assumptions are wrong, you can't usefully use that function anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is *a priori* impossible, since when you add a symbol, you never specify its size: the `symAdd` function just takes a `SYMTAB_ID`, a name, an address, a type ID, and a group ID. Some of the predefined type IDs imply a size (or at least, imply enough information that you could examine the data at the address and infer a size), but other predefined type IDs do not; and even if they *all* did, the API still wouldn't have any way to know about user-defined types (since it just sees them as opaque integer identifiers).

Comment: That's right no information on symbol length is available from symbol table... I will use the output of a nm command on my object file to retrieve the length of symbols. That's not really straightforward but at less it does the job!